# Bash: How to eliminate all numeric characters in a string, but retain those inside brackets?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

How do I remove all the numbers in a string in bash but retain those numbers inside a parenthesis using awk?

Sample data which is stored in a .txt file:

```
(A678) John, 35 Apples and 9 Oranges
(E312) Mark, 12 Oranges
(B21) Brooke, 40 Bananas
```

Output:

```
(A678) John, Apples and Oranges
(E312) Mark, Oranges
(B21) Brooke, Bananas
```

Comment: Add what you have tried so far so we can help you with that. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(^| )[0-9]+( |$)/ /g' file
```

```
(A678) John, Apples and Oranges
(E312) Mark, Oranges
(B21) Brooke, Bananas
```

Comment: I tried this but getting an exception:
sed: invalid option -- E
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

Comment: Try: `sed -r 's/(^| )[0-9]+( |$)/ /g' file`

Comment: This will fail on something like: `string (string 74 string) string`

Comment: Or, if we accept the format but also accept a possible typo: `(A678) John,12 apples and 9 oranges`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample input/output you provided you seem to be asking how to implement one possible solution to your problem rather than asking about your problem, i.e. this appears to be an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/). This might be all you really need:

```
$ awk '{t=$1; gsub(/[0-9]/,""); $1=t} 1' file
(A678) John, Apples and Oranges
(E312) Mark, Oranges
(B21) Brooke, Bananas
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!~/\(|\)/ && $i~/[0-9]/){sub(/[0-9]+/,"",$i)}}} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed 's/\(\([^(0-9]*\(([^)]*)\)[^(0-9]*\)*\)[0-9]\+ */\1/g' file
```

Gather up all the possible characters you want to keep before one or more numeric characters followed by zero or more spaces, and replace them with the first collection. Do this globally throughout the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='[ \n]' '!/^[0-9]+$/{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' file
(A678) John, Apples and Oranges
(E312) Mark, Oranges
(B21) Brooke, Bananas
```

If the record (set using `RS`) isn't a number `!/^[0-9]+$/`, awk prints it.

As highlighted in the comment by @kvantour, this only works if numbers within parenthesis don't space. If so, you could use the following:

```
awk -v RS="[()\n]" 'RT!=")"{gsub(/[0-9]+ ?/,"")}!/^[0-9]+$/{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' file
```

This solution though won't work with nested or misaligned parenthesis.

Comment: This will fail on something like: `string (string 74 string) string`

Comment: @kvantour: maybe, but that is not what the question states as an input format.

Comment: The question states: _How do I remove all the numbers in a string in bash but retain those numbers inside a parenthesis using awk?_ While the example date has a particular format, the question does not make any reference to that format.